# Please preserve the "customize public view" feature

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs, privacy

Based on the answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136240/on-my-careers-profile-why-are-all-the-customize-public-view-checkboxes-greyed) it appears that the recent Careers 2.0 Profile email was directed at the "customize public view" feature. I would like to formally request that this feature be retained, because I happen to like it - I appreciate the control it gives me over my privacy.

For those who don't have access to or do not use this feature: it allows you to hide pieces of your Careers profile from public view, such as location, employment, or educational history.

Comment: I second this call to retain the ability to customize the public view of a Stack Careers CV/Profile.  I use this feature extensively myself and it's removal would reduce the value of SO careers for me.

Comment: I'm currently considering making a Careers 2.0 profile, and the lack of this feature is something of a deterrent for me. I'm surprised this has been declined. That seems rather Facebooky too me, and I thought StackExchange was better than that.